# counting syllables in an audio stream, in realtime

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

How viable would it be to do realtime audio processing on a typical smartphone? Specifically, I need to be able to count syllables as they're being spoken into a microphone. Accuracy is not that important, but it needs to be realtime(or close), so sending an audio recording to an external service for processing wouldn't work.

Comment: Hm, you should be able to use `AudioRecord` and FFTs to get frequency spectrum & strength - that is doable "sort-of-realtime" in live wallpapers even.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I'll look into that. I've never done any signal processing before and have no idea what is involved, but I figured detecting a sharp change in amplitude or frequency might correlate with syllables. I guess the fourier transform puts it in a format which facilitates this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you head down the road of trying to figure out FFT, I suggest you try using the MediaRecorder instead. It is far simpler than AudioRecord and you can use it to analyze amplitude differences. You can use the code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524182/sound-recognition-in-android/).

Also, there is a more complete implementation of the various code you need for a clapper inside of the [gastlib github project](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib).