# Sound API to convert voice to analog and digital signal for Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to convert voice it could be humming or in singing mode to analog and digital signal so that I can get a pattern and by this I can move the objects. I am already converted my voice into text speech(speech api is available for android). I have tried musicg api but not able to succeed. Could anyone please suggest any sound api, suggestion are welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Nimit

Comment: What do mean by "analog signal"? Are you talking about doing an FFT to process the audio data in the frequency domain? That would still be a digital signal.

Comment: Yes, you are right Michael. Is there any way to achieve this? This would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone from the android or java community, please share your views and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer following links:

[Sound recognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524182/sound-recognition-in-android)

https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/tree/master/library/src/root/gast/audio

https://code.google.com/p/josemariakim/source/browse/trunk/lab3/ClapController/ClapDetector.java

https://code.google.com/p/musicg/

And any other suggesstions are welcome.

Thanks