# Detect beep sound in android

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to detect beep sound or clap sound from the android device using mic

1.Is their any library available to do that ?

2. can i do this using Google tts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sound recognition in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524182/sound-recognition-in-android)

Comment: almost similar to the question but my need is different

Comment: In one of the answers of that question is suggested to take a look at TarsosDSP. It may fit your needs!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please Check Out the Below Api Url using which i am able to detect the whistle Sound and that may be support the Clap Sounds Also.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/musicg/