# Android compare two sounds for phonetic matching

Tags: android, voice

How can I compare two sounds for phonetic matching in android/Java?
Basically it's something simillar to voice recognition/text to speech, but Voice Recognition isn't available for my language. 
My application looks like this:
I have 10 persons saved in my database and for each one I would record a different sound(voice) and saved it.
Then on a press of a button I would record another sound and save it temporary. Now how can I compare this recording with 10 recordings of my people sounds and match to one person?

Comment: here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257075/real-time-audio-processing-in-android) this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

While the link listed does provide some guidance on audio analysis, I don't think that what you want to do is possible, as it would require frequency analysis to find the similarity of voices, which AFAIK isn't possible purely on device, and would be quite processor intensive.

I've done a similar thing which involved uploading recordings to a server and processing them using the server, then sending back the result, so if this is feasible I would recommend that route.